# Is it common for a Terraform resource to interact with multiple API groups or it should be 1:1 mapping?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Context: I'm developing a TF Provider and going through HashiCorp's [tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-setup).

I'm trying to come up with a resource definition and can't figure out which one to pick.

- Option #1:

```
Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
    "name": {
        Type:         schema.TypeString,
        Required:     true,
    },
    "endpoint": {
        Type:        schema.TypeString,
        Required:    true,
    },
},

resource "foo" "bar" {
  name = "alex"
  endpoint = "https://api.stripe.com" # unique for every bar
}
```

- Option #2:

```
Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
    "name": {
        Type:         schema.TypeString,
        Required:     true,
    },
    "district_id": {
        Type:        schema.TypeString,
        Required:    true,
    },
},


resource "foo" "bar" {
  name = "alex"
  district_id = "NE53DE" # unique for every bar
}
```

The advantage of #1 is it follows the API and in order to perform CRUD operations TF Provider can interact with just one API group (there's 1:1 mapping between API Group and resource).

The advantage of #2 is it's more readable but in order to call API Group #1 we still need to figure out the endpoint so TF Provider has to call API Group #2 to retrieve that endpoint.

Which of these options is more commonly used when developing TF Providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're debating here is unfortunately probably the most crucial part of Terraform provider development: making tradeoffs and judgement calls about how best to translate Terraform's provider-agnostic lifecycle model to the physical constraints of a specific real API.

A big advantage of following closely the remote API design is that it's less likely that future expansion to the API design will invalidate your provider design. This can be particularly important if the provider is being designed by someone who doesn't directly work with the team which designs the API, since the provider developer then typically cannot predict how the API is likely to be changed in future and what design principles the API design team typically follow when considering new use-cases.

However, as you've noted real-world APIs are often not designed for convenient direct use, and are instead designed to expose raw building blocks on the assumption that others will build suitable *use-case specific* abstractions on top. A Terraform provider developer ends up in a somewhat tough spot here because they are usually also trying to provide a general solution (*not* focused on a specific use-case) but also want to design something that is relatively convenient to use within the Terraform language.

I cannot offer specific advice due to not having sufficient context about the API you are designing for or your design goals for the provider, but I can at least offer a potential opportunity for compromise: *data sources*.

Along with the managed resource types which represent Terraform directly managing some object in a remote system, Terraform also supports *data* resource types ("data sources" for short), which appear in the Terraform language as [`data` blocks](https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources#using-data-sources). These essentially model *external dependencies* of a particular module, by which I mean objects that the module expects someone else to have already created and which the module needs to declare the objects it will itself manage (its *managed* resources).

If your mapping from "district ID" to "endpoint" could in some sense be conceived as an external object then a data source could help fill the gap here. Don't worry too much about whether it really *is* a first-class object in the remote system; what's important here is whether it's reasonable for a Terraform module author to think of it as one, such that they can represent your "figure out the endpoint" requirement as a data resource:

```
data "foo_district_endpoint" "example" {
  district_id = "NE53DE"
}

resource "foo" "bar" {
  name     = "alex"
  endpoint = data.foo_district_endpoint.example.endpoint
}
```

This then makes explicit this need you described of making an API request to determine the endpoint from the district ID, rather than hiding it as an implementation detail of `foo`. An important advantage of making it explicit is that the module which looks it up might not always necessarily be the module that makes use of it; for configurations using [Module Composition](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/composition) patterns it's possible that these two needs will be split into two smaller modules and thus the `endpoint` value will flow from one to the other using output values and input variables.

The two possibilities you described and this third possibility I've added are all valid and defensible designs for different situations. Although I can't tell you which one is best for your specific situation, I hope this comment is at least helpful in giving you some things to consider in order to help you make the decision for yourself.